# Why am I not able to export my animation in the fbx file from blender?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender, fbx

I have created a kind of pipe like structure.In blender I am able to see the animation. But when I export  it to the .fbx file I am not able to see the animation. Also the same thing in Unity as well.What is wrong?

The fbx setting is:

```
path mode->copy (earlier I had gone to external data and packed all material into .blend file)
Limit to ->selected object ->empty,armature,mesh and other
apply scaling->fbx scale units
forward->Z forwards
unchecked leaf bones and a
under bake animation NLA strips,Force start/end...Also I tried with both of the checked in previous case
```

I am giveing the link of the .blend file.Please find it for reference.

https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1zgcRPNN3kdsH53cV-9TyAM1_XKxbcog2

Answer (score 1):

FBX and Unity does not support same animation functions as Blender. I see you have created the animation with explode modifier and particle system but FBX have no way how to represent that neither does Unity. Well Unity kind of does but its particle system is different than Blenders. Usualy when exporting animations from Blender to Unity the safe bet is creating animation using armature. Another way fot this specific case could be exporting exploded geometry as static object without animation and then do some math in Unity.